# angular screenshots webshot manage $rootScope like protractor do

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor

I'm using this snippet to build a page screenshot:

```
app.route('/auth/screenshot').post(function (req, res) {
            //var name = req.params.name;
            var webshot = require('webshot');
            var id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
                        var options = {
                            onLoadFinished: function() {
                                // Is there a way to manage to angular ?
                            }
                        };
        webshot(req.body.url, configs.rootPath +'/screenshots/'+ id +'.png', options, function(err) {
            if(!err){
                res.json({ id: id});
            }
        });
        });
```

and it work very well.
The problem is when ie I've got in the angular code

```
<div data-ng-if="!global.isAuthenticated">
```

the html is not showed.

Is there any way to work it out ?

Is there  a way to interact with angular in the onLoadFinished callback like protractor do ?

Comment: the ng-if directive will not render the html unless $scope.global.isAuthenticated is truthy. That logic is likely provided by a service on the client side -- hard to give you a concrete answer without more code from the client side or a jsfiddle/plunkr.

Comment: The question is: is there  a way to interact with angular in the onLoadFinished callback like protractor do ?

Comment: Ah, didn't see that comment earlier -- If I'm not mistaken, that is taking place on your backend (it looks like a nodejs / expressjs construct). AngularJS is on the front end.. nothing you do there will explicitly impact anything on the Angular side. So without more info / an example, it's hard to help you any further.

Comment: It's a mean stack I send from within the client (angular) $location.absUrl() to the server to build the screenshot and I'm looking for a way to manage angular stuff like global.isAuthenticated like proractor